# Nuxt3/vue3 how to show modal component that is called from header component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am using nuxt3/vue3. I am having a difficult time to call the modal based on my header component. I just put the modal inside the header component and use `Teleport` function to teleport the modal in the `body` based on the `showModal` value but it doesnt work. Here is what I tried

Header.vue

```
<template>
    <header class="header sticky-top">
        <nav class="container-fluid navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="row justify-content-start">
                    <div class="col text-end p-3">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" type="button" class="btn">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Modal v-show="showModal"/>
        </nav>
    </header>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Modal from '~~/components/Modal.vue';

export default {
    components:{
        Modal
    },
    data(){
        return{
            showModal: false
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

DefaultLayout.vue

```
<template>
        <Header />
            <main class="p-4 ">
                <div class="container-fluid ">
                    <slot />
                </div>
            </main>
        <Footer />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Header from '~~/components/Header.vue';
import Footer from '~~/components/Footer.vue';
export default {
    components: {
        Footer,
        Header
    },
}
</script>
```

index.vue (which is my homepage)

```
<template>
    <default-layout>
        <Listings/>
    </default-layout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import DefaultLayout from '~~/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue';
import Listings from '~~/components/Listings.vue';
export default {
    setup() {

    },
    components: {
        DefaultLayout,
        Listings
    }
}
</script>
```

Modal.vue

```
<template>
    <Teleport to="body">
        <div class="modal show" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Teleport>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default{
    props:{
        showModal: Boolean
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code looks good so far. So you need to find out which does not work? Is the modal teleported to the body? Or is the class `show` toggled correctly? Or is the style applied correctly to your modal?

Comment: hello @Duannx the modal doesnt show but when i look the dom. the modal element is in there.

Comment: Please answer all the questions above. That is the way we debug

Comment: @Duannx the modal element is appended in the body but it doesnt show and the style is not applied

Comment: Yeah. So we move to the question: Why is the style not applied? Does the class exist on the element? If yes, does the style apply to the correct class?

Comment: @Duannx yes it exists on the element. I dont have idea why the style is not applied

Comment: Is style added to your component? Is it applied to the correct class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251853/discussion-between-draw134-and-duannx).

Answer (score 2):

My current approach to modals is to mount the modal component into global app template and controll its visibility by a Pinia store variable:

- [example - app.vue](https://github.com/AloisSeckar/ELRHistory/blob/main/app.vue)
- [example - store](https://github.com/AloisSeckar/ELRHistory/blob/main/composables/useModalStore.ts)
- [example - modal](https://github.com/AloisSeckar/ELRHistory/blob/main/components/TheModal.vue)

I use Composition API, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Comment: i tried creating a stackblitz link maybe you can help 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-iwzps5?file=components/Modal.vue

Comment: I am not very familiar with Options API and reactivity, so I am not quite sure :( In my example I bypass that by introducing Pina data store to track the visibility outside components - https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#installation

Answer (score 0):

based on the response of @ellrohir, I have developed a simple method for Nuxt 3 with Pinia and Primevue

my store file modalStore.ts

```
export const useModalStore = defineStore({
    id: 'modal-store',
    state: () => {
        return {
            displayModal: false,
            modalTitle: '',
            modalText: '',
        };
    },
    actions: {
        showModal(title: string, text: string): void {
            this.modalTitle = title;
            this.modalText = text;
            this.displayModal = true;
        },
        closeModal(): void {
            this.displayModal = false;
        },
    },
});
```

my app.vue

```
<script setup>
    const modalStore = useModalStore();
</script>
<template>
    <DialogLogin />
</template>
```

my modal DialogLogin

```
<script setup>
    const modalStore = useModalStore();
</script>

<template>
    <Dialog
        :header="$t('login')"
        v-model:visible="modalStore.displayModal"
        :breakpoints="{ '960px': '75vw', '640px': '90vw' }"
        :style="{ width: '50vw' }"
        :position="position"
        :modal="true"
    >
        <!-- login component form -->
        <FormLogin />

        <!-- footer template -->
        <template #footer>
            <Button
                :label="$t('cancel')"
                icon="pi pi-times"
                @click="modalStore.closeModal()"
                class="p-button-text"
            />
        </template>
    </Dialog>
</template>
```

then I activate it with a button

```
        <Button
            label="Login"
            icon="pi pi-sign-in"
            @click="modalStore.showModal()"
        ></Button>
```